# Check background of item in table web using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, html-table

pic 1
[image: table]

pic 2

[image: htmlcode]

I have a table as pic 1. I need to find one invalid cell (valid: green-background, invalid: red-background). If they're all valid as picture, I must press to back previous page
I got script to get current page:

```
current_page =driver.find_element("//span[@class='currentPage']).get_attribute("innerText")
```

But I don't know how to loop through each cell of table to find which one valid or not to click or do other actions.

Thank your help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all elements with a certain class/css selector/whatever by using driver.find_elements_by_*whatever_you_want* . then you can loop through the elements by using a simple `for i in elements` loop and get the attribute for every element. you can then say what happens if the cell is valid or not.

Comment: Thanks @Timeler, I get a list of element through 

`valid_ext_list = driver.find_elements("xpath...")` 
but how could I click on any element inside that list?

Comment: well you can simply do "for i in valid_ext_list:
                                      i.click()